# CSS Adding a second droppanel

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to add a second drop panel after going through the:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/pure_css3_push_down_panel/

I am able to add a second drop panel, but I want to know how to change the image of the second drop panel without it affecting the first one.

Here's my header:

```
<style type="text/css">

div.css3droppanel { /* Main wrapper for push down panel */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2em; /* margin with rest of content on page */
  }


div.css3droppanel > div { /* Content DIV DIV inside wrapper */
  height: 100px; /* initial height of content when hidden. Should be same height as bottom bar (see div.css3droppanel:after) */
  padding: 5px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* ensure any padding and border declared inside content DIV doesn't increase DIV's declared dimensions */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff; /* background of content DIV */
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;  /* CSS3 transition of UL state. Last 0.1s specifies delay before animation */
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s; /* instead of ease-in-out, also try cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1.4) instead */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  }

div.css3droppanel input[type="checkbox"] { /* style invisible checkbox element used to toggle state of push down panel */
  position: absolute; 
  width: 60px; /* width of checkbox */
  height: 100px; /* height of checkbox */
  bottom: -34px; /* bottom offset of checkbox */
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  }

div.css3droppanel input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div { /* when checkbox is checked, expand content within wrapper */
  height: 500px; /* height of content to expand to. Scrollbar will be shown if content overflows this height */
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  }

div.css3droppanel label { /* style label that's positioned below wrapper's bottom bar, and will toggle checkbox when interacted with */
  position: absolute; 
  width: 60px; /* width of label */
  height: 100px; /* height of label */
  bottom: -34px; /* bottom offset of label */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5; 
  }

  /* for label 1 [WIP] */
div.css3droppanel label:after {
  content:url(https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg); 
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; 
  top: 18px; 
  }

</style>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>

<style>

/* Hide panel from IE8 and below */

div.css3droppanel {
  display: none;
  }


</style>

<![endif]-->
```

Here is the contents:

```
<div class="css3droppanel">
<input type="checkbox" id="droptoggle" />
<label for="droptoggle" title="Click to open Panel"></label>
<div class="content">
<p>
the first drop panel
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="css3droppanel">
<input type="checkbox" id="droptoggle" />
<label for="droptoggle" title="Click to open Panel"></label>
<div class="content">
<p>
the second drop panel
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Clicking on either one of the panels will open up the same set of text (The first drop panel), but I want them to each function individually.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and your panels are operating independently as long as you click directly on the checkbox for the input.

What happens when clicking on either image is the input is treated as a switch for the top checkbox instead of the check box you want it to relate to. This leads me to believe the issue is with either `div.css3droppanel label` or `div.css3droppanel label:after`.

Sorry I can't give you an exact answer but I hope this helps you pinpoint the problem

Comment: I've got the different panels functioning independantly through using different ID tags ('droptoggle', 'droptoggle2').

How would I reference different images on the panel within the `div.css3droppanel label:after {'?

Comment: Using ID Tags may work for the Images, failing that you could manually enter them in the html directly using the <img /> tag

Comment: I believe the image for the panel is within the div.css3 label:after
     
"content:url(https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg);"